# Creating application in tabris

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

I'm new to tabris and I'm trying to create a simple prototype:

> Login form --> list of possible actions --> action

In the EntryPoint I have implemented the createUI() method, creating a shell and inserting in the shell my 3 login fields and the login button.
Supposed that the login is correct I'd like to change to another 'screen', presenting a list of available actions (example: show status, my account, ...).

How to accomplish this?

How to store some data in session? (userid, username,...)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to store data in the Session you can use the SessionStore. See RWT.getSessionStore

Regarding the login screen: I would recommend to create it on a full screen composite. When the user logs in successfully dispose the composite and create one with your application. See the Widgets class for how to animate the new composite.

Hope this helps,

Cheers Holger